# Node and npm specific to an angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, nvm

I am working on an angular project(6) with node. I have some other projects already built on the lower versions of **ang+node+npm**.

I am trying to deploy it on to a server, Since there are different node+npm needed for different projects, facing difficulties to build them parallelly.

Tried to use nvm for the switching of nodes, but doing so the versions are getting changed globally which is not serving the purpose.

Anyone tried this already or can anyone help me on this?

Comment: *facing difficulties to build them parallelly* - what difficulties?

Comment: The node and npm are moving to a specified version with nvm globally, so the build is failing. I want that node and npm to be specific and effetcive with in the project. Can i do that ?

Comment: Generally, no. You can have local `npm` dep in project to be used in project.json scripts, but there's no guarantee that global `npm` won't be used instead. Usually there's no need to do that. Latest Node and NPM are backward compatible and should do the trick, especially with Angular toolchain because it's not exotic at all. If a project has problems, try to erase node_modules and reinstall. You will have much less problems with reinstallation if a project has package-lock.json (NPM5 and higher).